# XML column in SSIS has byte-order-mark

Tags: sql-server, xml, encoding, ssis

I'm using an oledb data source in an SSIS package to pull a column from a database. The column is XML data type. In SSIS, it is automatically recognized as data type DT_NTEXT. It's going to a script component where I'm trying to load it into a System.Xml.XmlDocument. This is the code that I'm using to get the xml data into a string:

```
System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(Row.Data.GetBlobData(0, Row.Data.Length))
```

Is this the correct way?

One odd thing that I'm seeing is that on one server, I get a byte-order-mark in the resulting string, and another server I don't. I wouldn't mind knowing why that is the case, but my real desire is how to get this string without the BOM.

Help me, Stack Overflow, you're my only hope...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the only way I was able to get it to work:

```
System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetString(...).Trim()
```

The .Trim() removes the BOM. I'm not sure if this is the "right" way, but it's the only thing that's worked so far.